# Adding defined variable to string formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the code below that compares a row with its subsequent row based on header content.

I want to expand this code sections to have the `StrDAirportCol & Headerrow +1` and `+2` check whether they have defined variables. e.g. `& strDAirportCol & HeaderRow + 1 ="AirportZY"`

I have rewritten it to

```
strDAirportCol & HeaderRow + 1 & ="AirportZY" & 
strDAirportCol & HeaderRow + 2 & = "AirportAB"
```

but I get a debug error.

This is the original code line I want to change

```
'CUSTOMS
strFormula = "=AND($" & strCountryCol & HeaderRow + 1 & "=$" & strCountryCol & _
  HeaderRow + 2 & ",$" & strDAirportCol & HeaderRow + 1 & "=$" & strDAirportCol & _
  HeaderRow + 2 & ",$" & strCustomCol & HeaderRow + 1 & "<>$" & strCustomCol & _
  HeaderRow + 2 & ")"

 With ActSht.Range(ActSht.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, CustomCol), 
  ActSht.Cells(LastRow,CustomCol) ) 
  .FormatConditions.Delete
  .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    strFormula
   With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count) 
     .SetFirstPriority
     With .Interior
       .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
       .TintAndShade = 0
     End With
   End With
 End With
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem like an optimal approach to whatever it is you're trying to do. Couldn't we just have VBA calculate the value you want to go into a cell so that you don't need to create a big weird formula like this?

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero, the strformula is part of the format.conditions to highlight the cells. I added the code above. currently the code just compares the value of two cells and if they differ apply red highlight. For my revision I want it to check that for a certain value and compare that one to another.

Comment: I'm afraid even with the explanation above, in comments, what you're trying to do still isn't clear. What do you mean by "whether they have defined variables"? You will certainly get an error with the two code lines standing on their own in the question, with the `&` at the end of the first line - it's missing ` _` to bind it to the following line. Or the `&` needs to be removed if the second line should stand on its own. In addition, the `= ` in both lines needs to be within the `"`. Compare these two lines to the ones in the code that do work...